# relocating legend of flot plot

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm using flot as a plotting javascript utility.
Here is the sample I'm using which allows toggle...
https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/examples/series-toggle/index.html

What I want to achieve is to move the legend to the right side of the plot as having several curves causes the legend to grow big and block the view.
I tried the "aboveData" option as the api suggested:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", data, {
                    yaxis: {
                        min: 0
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        tickDecimals: 0
                    },grid: {show:true, aboveData:false},
                });
```

It did not do anything.
Then I tried changing the css to add a "left" property to the table:

```
.legend table {
    border-spacing: 5px;
    left:800px;
}
```

which does move the legend table to right but there is an opaque white div container left behind.
Any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method kinda works if you use the parent `legend` div instead of the table:

```
.legend {
    position: absolute;
    left:800px;
}
```

This is probably not the best way to achieve your goals though.  `flot` [provides the ability](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-legend) to relocate the legend to a container (div) of your choice.  So to put the legend right of the plot, I'd do:

```
<div id="flotGraph" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; float: left"></div>
<div id="legendContainer" style="float: left"></div>
```

And then use the legend container property:

```
    $.plot("#placeholder", data, {
        yaxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        xaxis: {
            tickDecimals: 0
        },
        legend: {
            container: $('#legendContainer')
         }
      });
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rajmjaox/).